# Notice for digest unsubscription doesn't use translation

Tags: bug, localization, subscription, unsubscribe

When you did unsubscription for the community digest, the notice appeared, e.g., on [ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/email/digests/current):

> [image]

> You have been unsubscribed

This text was [translated a long time ago](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/4391), but for some reason it was not used. A potential problem is that the real notice has a dot at the end, but there isn't any such source string to translate.